# Multiple automatic subdomains and URL rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to create automatic subdomains using Apache 2 (running on a Ubuntu box)

I have used the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive to do the initial declaring of the document root, with the following in my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/dev/branches/%1/public/
ServerAlias *.dev.example.com
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works well for the first part, so a request to `foo.dev.example.com` has a document root of `/var/www/dev/branches/foo/public`, which is great.

## The problem

Alas, the `*.htaccess` file I have in the public folders doesn't seem to be working.

All requests should be sent through index.php in the public folder, as the `.htaccess` file shows:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on  
  # redirects requests to index.php where no file or directory exists
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php
</IfModule>
```

A request to `foo.dev.example.com` works, but a request to `foo.dev.example.com/subdir` fails.

Help!

### Edit:

I have an error log that shows this is a mod_rewrite problem:

```
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [error] [client 217.206.134.99] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3063): [client 217.206.134.99] r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 217.206.134.99] redirected from r->uri = /user/login
[Thu Aug 04 14:05:45 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 217.206.134.99] Zlib: Compressed 630 to 389 : URL /var/www/dev/branches/amy/public/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this more or less working using these rules:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The only problem with this is, if there is a default index page in one of the directories, it can only be accessed directly, http://domain.tld/subdir/index.php
Just using http://domain.tld/subdir/ would rewrite it to http://domain.tld/index.php

Comment: Thanks derchris, but this gave the exact same redirection errors in Apache.

Comment: I tested it on mine, and worked